# creating a 2D array from String arrays

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I have built a program which takes 13 comma separated values of user input and appends them into a text file, each to a new line. Not too difficult, but I am new.

Now I am trying to bring these single line arrays back from the file into a 2D array where I hope to work with the values. I think I am close, but there is an obvious mistake that my inexperience does not allow me to see. *I also know that there are much better class strategies written to handle this task, but again . . . newbie.*

What I think is happening is that the entire file is being written into one location in the 2D array(I can sysout the finalArray , and it looks right, but only in position [0][0]). So how do I get each "z" to fill in the next open slot as it processes through ?. Hope you can help, here is my code:

```
String[][] finalArray = new String[100][13];            
int i=-1;       
try 
{ 
  x = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(readFile));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) 
{
   e1.printStackTrace();        
}       
try 
{   
    while ((line = x.readLine()) != null)           
    {   
        String[] y = line.split(separator);             
        try 
        {
            z ="["+ y[0] + "," + y[1] + "," + y[2] + "," + y[3]
+ "," + y[4] + "," + y[5] + "," + y[6] + "," + y[7]
+ "," + y[8] + "," + y[9] + "," + y[10] + y[11]
+ "," + y[12] + "," + y[13]+"]";
            finalArray[i+1][0] = z;
```

Answer (score 0):

`z`  is not array it is a `String`  but You have  array of string array
therefore your loop must look like this

```
i=0; // array starts with 0 Item
while ((line = x.readLine()) != null)           
{   
    finalArray[i++] = line.split(separator);
 }
```